# How to access all routes from Slim 3 php framework?

Tags: php, slim, psr-7

I am trying to build a dynamic drop-down menu from routes defined in Slim framework and here is my question - is there a way to access all defined static routes from some kind of array?

For instance, if I define my routes like this:

```
// Index page: '/'
require_once('pages/main.php');

// Example page: '/hello'
require_once('pages/hello.php');

// Example page: '/hello/world'
require_once('pages/hello/world.php');

// Contact page: '/contact'
require_once('pages/contact.php');
```

Each file is a separate page that looks like this

```
// Index page
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    // Some code

})->setName('index');
```

I would like to access all of these defined routes from some sort of array and then use that array to make a unordered HTML list in my template files.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Index</a></li>
  <li><a href="/hello">Hello</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="/hello/world">World</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Whenever I change defined routes, I would like this menu to change with it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: [The same question for Slim 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680412/slim-4-get-all-routes-into-a-controller-without-app).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick search of the [Router class in GitHub project for Slim](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Router.php) shows a public method `getRoutes()`, which returns the `$this->routes[]` array of route objects. From the route object you can get the route pattern using the `getPattern()` method:

```
$routes = $app->getContainer()->router->getRoutes();
// And then iterate over $routes

foreach ($routes as $route) {
    echo $route->getPattern(), "<br>";
}
```

**Edit**: Added example

Comment: But it returns a bunch of `Route` [objects](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Route.php), which is, probably, not what OP needs.

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov Yes, but you can pick out the properties within each object to print as you iterate the array.

Comment: This seems to work as I wanted. Thanks Wolf! I have made it in a way to put `$container['allRoutes'] = $app->getContainer()->router->getRoutes();` in PHP file after all pages were loaded with `require_once` and then use from within pages `$routes = $this->allRoutes;`. Is this approach ok?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can [name your routes](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#route-names) in Slim. This is done in a very simple manner:

```
$app->get('/hello', function($request, $response) {
    // Processing request...
})->setName('helloPage'); // setting unique name for route
```

Now you can get URL by name like this:

```
$url = $app->getContainer()->get('router')->pathFor('helloPage');
echo $url; // Outputs '/hello'
```

You can name routes with placeholders too:

```
// Let's define route with placeholder
$app->get('/user-profile/{userId:[0-9]+}', function($request, $response) {
    // Processing request...
})->setName('userProfilePage');

// Now get the url. Note that we're passing an array with placeholder and its value to `pathFor`
$url = $app->getContainer()->get('router')->pathFor('helloPage', ['userId': 123]);
echo $url; // Outputs '/user-profile/123'
```

This is sure the way to go, because if you reference routes by names in your templates, then if you need to change a URL, you need to do it only in route defenition. I find this particuarly cool.

Answer (score 2):

as i've commented in the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1456#issuecomment-455262373) of slim:

```
$routes = array_reduce($this->app->getContainer()->get('router')->getRoutes(), function ($target, $route) {
    $target[$route->getPattern()] = [
        'methods' => json_encode($route->getMethods()),
        'callable' => $route->getCallable(),
        'middlewares' => json_encode($route->getMiddleware()),
        'pattern' => $route->getPattern(),
    ];
    return $target;
}, []);
die(print_r($routes, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Wolf's answer, I have made my solution.

In a page where you define routes, below all of them we will make a container with our defined routes.

```
// Get ALL routes
// --------------
$allRoutes = [];
$routes = $app->getContainer()->router->getRoutes();

foreach ($routes as $route) {
  array_push($allRoutes, $route->getPattern());
}

$container['allRoutes'] = $allRoutes;
```

This will create an array with needed routes that we can use later in our project.

Then from within your defined routes, you can call this like this:

```
$app->get('/helloWorld', function ($request, $response, $args) {

  print_r ($this->allRoutes);

})->setName('helloWorld');
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => /
    [1] => /helloWorld
    [2] => /someOtherRoute
    ...
)
```

so that we can use this array to create whatever we want. Thanks again Wolf!

Comment: It won't. Only static routes.

Comment: it would also be worth getting the data of `$route->getMethods()` to know whether the route is `GET` / `POST` etc